# Loaded die problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rigid-body-dynamics

A loaded die has an uneven mass density distribution. A given die is constructed from a square pyramid of material with mass density $\rho_1$ whose bsase lays on the face marked "1",with the rest of the cube made of a material of mass density $\rho_2$. What is the die's tensor of moment of inertia? What are the odds of the die falling on each of its sides?

What do you think?

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41297/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Dear InonS - Check out Qmechanic's link and see whether you can reason an answer from that, and then change your question accordingly. Your question might be a duplicate, but it certainly is an excellent question notwithstanding the close votes: I for one wouldn't have a clue where to begin (aside from the other question's answer) unless I thought about this hard for several days and even then I might even draw a blank.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I indeed looked at the linked question before posting mine, and finally decided this merits a separate question. Particularly, my version of the problem is such that it could occur in a real life gambling fraud situation, whereas a non-cubic die would be easily identified!

Comment: Would anyone be willing to place a bounty on my question? Regretfully, I'm not presently privileged to do so...