# Rolling a 14-sided die

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, probability, geometry

Suppose we make a 14 sided die by taking a cube and slicing a triangular pyramid off each corner, such that there are now 6 square faces and 8 triangular faces, each with unit side length (in other words, a cuboctahedron).

*Assuming that the die is an evenly weighted solid and rolled with plenty of energy, what is the probability of it landing on a square (and hence with a square face up)?*

There are two values that I know of that might yield insight to this problem.

**Centre of Mass**: the die seems more likely to remain on a face which lowers its centre of mass.

**Area**: the die seems more likely to land on a face with greater area.

The square both has a larger area, and a lower centre of mass; indicating that surely it is more likely to be landed on. But exactly how much more likely - and could such a probability be calculated as a function of the centre of mass and/or area?

Comment: Well, the answer to your question depends on the base area of each pyramid, doesn't it?

Comment: I guess the solid you are describing is a [cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron), isn't it?

Comment: I think this is more suited for physics stackexchange. This is because here one assume that the physical model is trivial or given which is not true in this case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is essentially a maths question.

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/41353/26969

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I model rolling a die without actually rolling it, based on [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1879731/357390):

> Cast a ray from the die's centre of mass in a random direction. Whichever face the ray passes through is the face the die lands on.

In other words, the probability of a (convex) polyhedron landing on a given face is the solid angle subtended by that face at the centre of mass divided by $4\pi$ (the solid angle of a sphere).

In the case of the cuboctahedron the centre of mass is the geometric centre. We can work out the solid angle $\Omega$ subtended by a square face, noting that it forms a square pyramid with base side length 1 and height $\frac{\sqrt2}2$. Using the formula provided on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Pyramid):
$$\Omega=4\tan^{-1}\frac{1^2}{2\frac{\sqrt2}2\sqrt{4\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)^2+1^2+1^2}}=4\tan^{-1}\frac1{\sqrt8}$$
The proportion of $4\pi$ this is then works out to
$$\Box=\frac{4\tan^{-1}\frac1{\sqrt8}}{4\pi}=\frac{\tan^{-1}\frac1{\sqrt8}}\pi=0.108173\dots$$
This is for one square face. To get the probability of landing on any square face, multiply by six:
$$6\Box=\frac{6\tan^{-1}\frac1{\sqrt8}}\pi=0.649040\dots$$
Thus the cuboctahedral die described has around a 65% chance of landing on square faces, or around an 11% chance of landing on a given square face.

Comment: This and that model is seriously flawed. We know from experience that flipping a dollar coin almost always lands on head or tail, but this model predicts it to land on the edge 7% of the tosses (the edge area is 7% of the coin area) - how often do that happen in reality?

Comment: @skyking The way coins are thrown varies a lot between people, and none of those ways are mathematically ideal. Furthermore, a coin is never a perfect cylinder (due to milling, inscriptions, wear, etc.) and the irregularities cause the coin to tip towards head or tail if it lands on the edge first. Since this is a mathematical model I can only talk in the ideal sense, without the variations introduced in reality.

Comment: Do you really think that irregularities of the edge is the only thing that makes the coin end up on either side? I don't think that's a reasonable explaination. These factors do not help your model, even with a perfect cylinder you would probably not observe 7% edge.  Besides your model wouldn't be affected by these factors anyway.

Comment: @skyking I forgot to mention inertia. That was something I had considered while writing the other dice answer, and it was agreed there that it introduces too many variables to be adequately represented in a model. Also affecting the coin's result are the ground and any energy losses due to sound or friction.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is not really a model for rolling a die, but rather for releasing it above a flat surface that absorbs all its kinetic energy (after randomly orienting it). Alternatively this could be seen as a model in which the cuboctahedron is projected on a sphere centered on its centre of mass and which is then dropped (or rolled).

Comment: This answer is wrong even when you consider only the static stability of the die and not its dynamic stability. For some polyhedra the CG does not lie vertically above all faces. The die cannot come to rest on those faces, which therefore have zero probability. If the CG lies vertically above a face but close to an edge,  it is likely to topple onto the adjacent face and therefore have low probability.